# How to match this using SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using the 3 following tables:

**First table**

- id
- response

**Second table**

- responseid
- patientid

**Third table**

- patientid

The relationship between first and second table is on `id` and `responceid`.

The relationship between third and second is on `patientid`.

Now I need to retrieve values from these tables like all values from first and third  tables with the help of matching with `patientid` from second and 3rd table.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Basically if all of the columns that defines their relationship are not nullable, then `INNER JOIN` will suffice. But if they are *nullable* and you still want to display all records from `firstTB`, you need to use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*, c.*
FROM    firstTB a
        INNER JOIN secondTB b
            ON a.ID = b.responceID
        INNER JOIN thirdTB c
            ON b.patientID = c.patientID
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for `INNER JOIN` or `JOIN` in general:

```
SELECT
    response.id,
    response.responce,
    patient.patientid
FROM
    `response_table` as `response`
INNER JOIN
    `relation_table` as `relation`
ON
    relation.responceid = response.id
INNER JOIN
    `patient_table` as `patient`
ON
    relation.patientid = patient.patientid
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    SELECT first.*
         , third.*
      FROM first
INNER JOIN second  ON ( second.responseid = first.id )
INNER JOIN third   ON ( third.patientid   = second.patientid )
         ;
```

honestly, and no insult intended, if you have difficulties in coming up with queries like this one on your own, consider some training on db basics and db development, the sooner the better (just hoping i haven't blundered myself ... ;-)).